# Implementation of the MPEG-4 standard Part 16 (Animation Framework Extension)

Tags: compression, mesh, mpeg, afx

I've been having a look at 3D mesh compression; our application produces a stream of 3D surfaces that we need to save to disk and if possible apply compression to.

I came across the [MPEG 4 animation framework extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4)   which seems to do what I want and also has the advantage of being an international standard. However, I can't seem to find a readily available implementation of the MPEG-4 AFX and I was wondering if anyone here knows where I can look.

EDIT: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm looking for a C/C++ library that implements the MPEG-4 AFX standard.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is an open source implementation of this standard. Please have a look here and don't hesitate to ask the contributors if you need additional help:
http://www.mymultimediaworld.com/software/opensource/